# Unexpected PN53x reply

Tags: kali-linux

I have a qprox qp3000 scanner. When I use lsusb it shows it's connected as follow

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
```

It is attached to USBtty0 according to dmesg but when I run nfc-list it brings the following error. Please help I am stuck

```
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
error   libnfc.chip.pn53x   Unexpected PN53x reply!
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_uart    pn53x_check_communication error
error   libnfc.chip.pn53x   Unexpected PN53x reply!
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: pn532_uart:/dev/ttyUSB0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try check /etc/nfc/libnfc.conf for configuration parameters.
Uncomment **#device.connstring = "pn532_uart:/dev/ttyUSB0"** if it hasn't yet.